# Get status of client computer Hardware Status

Tags: c#, network-programming, hardware, wmi

Hi
I have been given the assignment to check that if it is possible to check for hardware status (Mouse ,keyboard etc etc i.e conflicted devices )of each client System. Clients may be connected via LAN or WIFI.

I know this can be done on single computer like my application should be installed on a computer and i can get all the data via WMI but how to get this data remotely

Comment: Is installing your application on each of the client computers an option? You can use WMI to connect (and get information from) to remote computers but it does involve some configuration. If these are machines under your control then you can do it this way. See here more more details http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290(v=vs.85).aspx

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WMI is explicitly meant to be used remotely check out [this](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389290%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) and see if it helps.